# How can i play EA SPORT CRICKET(TM)2011 on ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, games

I am using 12.04 ubuntu,i want to play EA SPORT CRICKET(TM)2011 on my loptop.
please tell me step by step process.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/). You can install it using the Software Center. It is kind of hard to give step by step instructions since I don't own the game but PlayOnLinux has an easy assistant.

For starters: Klick `Install`. In the following menu you can select predefined profiles. Sadly there is none for your game so you have to do it manually. Klick `Install a non-listed program` in the lower left corner. Just follow the assistant. You want to create a new virtual drive. At some point it will ask you for the installer. Just enter your game disk (or whatever you have) an select the `.exe` file that will install the game.

There is no guarantee that your game will work on Ubuntu but this is the easiest way to try.